# Code::Blocks crashes :Process returned (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, crash, codeblocks

I am trying to build and run the following code on code blocks, but it crashes and returns the (0xC0000005) error. I mainly suspect the usage of realloc for pointer n_k in gCRSF_gibbs function, however I am not sure how to track the source of crash. This is not my original code and I am also a noob in C. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int BinarySearch(double probrnd, double *prob_cumsum, int Ksize) {
int k, kstart, kend;
if (probrnd <=prob_cumsum[0])
    return(0);
else {
    for (kstart=1, kend=Ksize-1; ; ) {
        if (kstart >= kend) {
            return(kend);
        }
        else {
            k = kstart+ (kend-kstart)/2;
            if (prob_cumsum[k-1]>probrnd && prob_cumsum[k]>probrnd)
                kend = k-1;
            else if (prob_cumsum[k-1]<probrnd && prob_cumsum[k]<probrnd)
                kstart = k+1;
            else
                return(k);
        }
    }
}
return(k);}
void gCRSF_gibbs(double *z, double *n_k, double *SampleDex,
             double *r, double *a, double *p,
             int *Ksize, int *WordNum) {

int i, j, k;
double mass;

double *prob_cumsum;
double cum_sum, probrnd;
void *newptr;

prob_cumsum = (double *) calloc(Ksize[0],sizeof(double));

mass = r[0]*pow(p[0],-a[0]);
for (i=0;i<WordNum[0];i++){
    j = (int) SampleDex[i] -1;
    k = (int) z[j] -1;
    if(z[j]>0){
        n_k[k]--;
    }
    for (cum_sum=0, k=0; k<Ksize[0]; k++) {
        cum_sum += n_k[k]-a[0];
        prob_cumsum[k] = cum_sum;
    }

    if ( ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * (cum_sum + mass) < cum_sum)){
        probrnd = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX*cum_sum;
        k = BinarySearch(probrnd, prob_cumsum, Ksize[0]);
    }
    else{
        for (k=0; k<Ksize[0]; k++){
            if ((int) n_k[k]==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if (k==Ksize[0]){
            Ksize[0]++;
            newptr = realloc(n_k,sizeof(*n_k)*Ksize[0]);
            n_k = newptr;
            n_k[Ksize[0]-1]=0;
            prob_cumsum =  realloc(prob_cumsum,sizeof(*prob_cumsum)*Ksize[0]);
        }
    }
    z[j] = k+1;
    n_k[k]++;
}
free(prob_cumsum);}

int main() {
double *z, *n_k, *sampleDex;
double *r, *a, *p;
int *Ksize, *WordNum;
z[0]=1;z[1]=1;z[2]=2;z[3]=0;z[4]=0;
n_k[0]=2;n_k[1]=1;
sampleDex[0]=4;sampleDex[1]=5;
r[0]=5;a[0]=0.5;p[0]=0.5;
Ksize[0]=2;WordNum[0]=2;
gCRSF_gibbs(z,n_k,sampleDex,r,a,p,Ksize,WordNum);
return 0;}
```

Comment: Your code is not only badly formatted, it uses many questionable practices. Your variables `r`, `a` and `p` are scalars, not arrays; treat them as such. You try to reallocate an array that was passed into the function by value, which isn't a good idea; a local dynamic array should probably be a copy of the input. And `sampleDex` and `n_k` are indices; these arrays should be integer types, not floating-point. (The many casts are a giveaway. Your code shouldn't need any casts if you use the proper types.) It is also not clear whet the output or reslt of `gCRSF_gibbs` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's reduce your problem to a minimal example that exhibits the same behaviour:

```
int main()
{
    double *z;

    z[0] = 1;       // Undefined behaviour!

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `z` is an uninitialized pointer; it points to a random location. De-referencing it, that is trying to read or write to where the pointer points to leads to undefined behavior.

You use `z` as an array of 5 floating-point numbers. The easiest way to fix this is to create `z` as a local array:

```
double z[5] = {1, 1, 2, 0, 0};
```

There are probably more errors in your code. This answer addresses only the cause of the obvious segmentation violation.

Comment: Similar errors occur for `n_k`, `sampleDex` `r` `a`, `p`, `Ksize` and `WordNum` pointers

Comment: @Rishi: Yes, and `r`, `a` and `p` don't have to be pointers in the first place. They are really scalars that are passed as pointers ond only used for reading, say, `r[0]` in `gCRSF_gibbs`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the definition of arrays and also omitted the pointer definition for scalars r, a, p, Ksize and NumWord in both functions, and it works fine now. But, the problem is I need to call this function (not the main() as it is just for a testing!) in R and therefore all input arguments, even scalars, are required to be pointers. In that case, I still face the crashing. Do you have any guess on why r,a and p can't be pointers in gCRSF_gibbs? Appreciate your time.

Comment: @Siamak: Oh, they can be pointers, it just doesn't make sense to make them pointers. If the R interface requires it, pass them as single-element arrays. (But you could define `double r` and pass it as `&r` is you test code instead.)

Comment: I defined the scalars as arrays; i.e. double r[1]={7}; and passed them to gCRSF_gibbs. Again the code blocks crashed!

Comment: Also in R I can't pass the address. I can only pass the variable using .C function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks, but it [supports debugging](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks). Please learn how to debug, it will tell you where your program crashed. For example, in the first pass, `k` will be -1, which isn't a vaid array index. And when you have crated a local array `n_k` in main, you can't `realloc` it; you can only re-allocate what you have explicitly allocated with ´malloc` or `calloc`.